# Can p-value for Spearman correlation be calculated from only the correlation coefficient and the sample size?

Tags: p-value, spearman-rho

When searching for p-value, I realized that the p-value for Pearson correlation can be calculated by simply knowing the correlation coeffiecient and the sample size, as illustrated in this website [P-value calculator](http://vassarstats.net/tabs_r.html). 
I'm wondering whether you can do the same thing using Spearman correlation, and why?